# Append a td to the first row of a table Object with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I know that this should be super easy but I haven't figured it out yet. I'd like to append a < td> to the first row of my table. I tried with this:

```
$table.get('tr:first').append("<td>Well "+(wellN)+"</td>");
```

But it didn't work. I also used this:

```
$($table +' tr:first').append("<td>Well "+(wellN)+"</td>");
```

But as expected, I got the following error:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]

Everything else is working right with my table Object.

Comment: Are you sure about `$table` and `wellN` being what you think they should be?

Comment: just a guess, but have you tried appendTo() ?

Comment: try using `$table.find('tr:first').append("<td>Well "+wellN+"</td>");`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `.find()` as `.get()` only takes in integers as a parameter:

From the docs:

> A zero-based integer indicating which element to retrieve.

So change out `.get()` for `.find()`:

```
$table.find('tr:first').append("<td>Well "+(wellN)+"</td>");
```

This assumes that `$table` is a jQuery object of the table element you want to alter. E.g. `$table = $('table');`

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/SRsnq/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKjvH/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>    
<a>click me</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('table').find('tr:first').append('<td>Works!</td>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$table.find('tr:first').append("<td>Well "+(wellN)+"</td>");
```

Comment: `$.get()` is an AJAX method, `$(selector).get()` is not: http://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$table.find('tr').first().append('<td>:)</td>')
```

[more info](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$("#mytable tr:first").append($("<td>").text("Foo"));
```